# How to use Python Kivy RecycleView in another layout without using Kivy language?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to use [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) in another layout without using Kivy language, but I couldn't display the data on the Window. What did I write bad or miss in my code?
I know kv language is good, but I don't want to use it in this small project.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

class MainWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_layouts()

    def create_layouts(self):
        self.create_recycle_view()

    def create_recycle_view(self):
        recycle_view = RecycleView()
        recycle_view.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(20)]
        recycle_view.viewclass = 'Label'
        recycle_box_layout = RecycleBoxLayout()
        recycle_box_layout.size_hint = (1, 0.2)
        recycle_view.add_widget(recycle_box_layout)
        self.add_widget(recycle_view)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be some strange side effects with some of the `RecycleView` classes, resulting in `viewclass` being set to `None`. So setting `viewclass` must be done later than in your code. Also, I believe that the building of the `RecycleView` should not be done in the `__init__()` method of the `MainWidget`. So, based on that, a modified version of your code that works is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView


class MainWidget(FloatLayout):

    def create_layouts(self):
        self.create_recycle_view()

    def create_recycle_view(self):
        recycle_box_layout = RecycleBoxLayout(default_size=(None, dp(56)), default_size_hint=(1, None),
                                              size_hint=(1, None), orientation='vertical')
        recycle_box_layout.bind(minimum_height=recycle_box_layout.setter("height"))
        recycle_view = RecycleView()
        recycle_view.add_widget(recycle_box_layout)
        recycle_view.viewclass = 'Label'
        self.add_widget(recycle_view)
        recycle_view.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(20)]


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_rv)
        return MainWidget()

    def add_rv(self, dt):
        self.root.create_layouts()


MainApp().run()
```

This code uses `Clock.schedule_once()` (in the `build()` method of the `App`) to build the `RecycleView`. Also, the `height` of the `RecycleBoxLayout` is bound to its `minimum_height` property.

Comment: Can I ask, why is it bad to do the building of the RecycleView in the __init__() method of the MainWidget? Here is my GitHub link for the project: https://github.com/kadamQ/forditoprogramok-beadando for more clarify.

Comment: Actually, there is no problem with building the `RecycleView` in the `__init__()` method, you just have to be careful about it. Be aware that some things are not available in the `__init__()` method, like the `ids`.